# StandardValueSetTranslation retrieval yields an UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION

Tags: metadata-api

In my dev sandbox, I get the following exception when I try to use the `package.xml` provided below to download my `StandardValueSetTranslations`.

**Error**

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION msg: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1793346980-32505 (2087119523)

**Package**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StandardValueSetTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

I get a similar error when I try to perform a `listMetadata()` in my dev sandbox, with a query of type `StandardValueSetTranslation`:

**Error**

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1260064296-52856 (-419197380)

I tried both API 38 and 39 in the package and in the `listMetadata()` call. I tried with the `salesforce_ant_38.0.zip` and `salesforce_ant_39.0.zip` API jars.

All other objects I try to retrieve seem to work fine. The same `package.xml` for instance, changing `StandardValueSetTranslation` to `StandardValueSet` works for me with no error.

I found that it also works in other Orgs, so it is either Spring '17 related, or sandbox related, or something is wrong with my specific org.

Comment: I don't see any reference to that gack available on the Internet. You need to log a case with support.

Comment: Did you try to specify the name of you element instead of using the * ? i.e.:<members>AccountRating-fr</members> resource : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvaluesettranslation.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't add a name, as I wasn't able to list the names with the listMetadata() operation. Other object types list that they don't work with * when they don't, so I would expect this one to work.